# How to put list from one element into a cell of a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I do the following:

```
df_temp = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2], [3, 4]], columns=['column1', 'column2'])

df_temp.at[0, 'column3'] = ['element1']

df_temp.at[1, 'column3'] = [['element1']]
```

But neither gives me a list with only one element in a cell

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the loc function.

```
df_temp.loc[index,column] = value
```

for example

```
df_temp.loc[0,'column1'] = 7
```

will replace the 1 as 7

Comment: No, I need exactly a list, i.e. type(df_temp.at[0, 'column3']) is list

Comment: with the sample data u have shown it, its 1D. You are basically trying to say, your column1 and column2 will have single values, but column3 will have a list ?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by

```
df_temp.loc[1, 'column3'] = [['element1']]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's your options:

```py
In [44]: df_temp['column3'] = [['element_1'], ['element_2']]

In [45]: df_temp
Out[45]:
   column1  column2      column3
0        1        2  [element_1]
1        3        4  [element_2]

In [46]: df_temp['column3'][0]
Out[46]: ['element_1']

In [47]: len(df_temp['column3'][0])
Out[47]: 1

In [48]: type(df_temp['column3'][0])
Out[48]: list
```

You need to make sure that you column type is 'object' type because lists are objects. You can also do:

```py
df_temp['new_col'] = None

df_temp.at[0, 'new_col'] = [1, 2]
```

Answer (score 0):

The behaviour of the above assignment is inconsistent

NOTE: This does not answer the user's question completely but gives more context

1. If I assign 1D list in both rows then it is storing it 1st as single string but second as list in cell

```py
df_temp = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2], [3, 4]], columns=['column1', 'column2'])


df_temp.at[0, 'column3'] = ['element1']

df_temp.at[1, 'column3'] = ['element1']

column1 column2 column3
0   1   2   element1
1   3   4   [element1]

# column1   column2 column3
# 0 1   2   element1
# 1 3   4   [element1]
```

2. If I assign 1st element as 2D list then assign second row with just 1d list it is storing both as 1D list in cell

```py
df_temp = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2], [3, 4]], columns=['column1', 'column2'])


df_temp.at[0, 'column3'] = [['element1']]

df_temp.at[1, 'column3'] = ['element1']

# column1   column2 column3
# 0 1   2   [element1]
# 1 3   4   [element1]
```

3. IF I assign 2D list for both rows then it is storing 1st as 1D list but second as 2D list

```py
df_temp = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2], [3, 4]], columns=['column1', 'column2'])


df_temp.at[0, 'column3'] = [['element1']]

df_temp.at[1, 'column3'] = [['element2']]

# column1   column2 column3
# 0 1   2   [element1]
# 1 3   4   [[element2]]
```

I think this has something to do with dtype of column but it is confusing. Is it a bug or expected behaviour